# How to change the value of favicon from false to true and vise-versa when clicked?

Tags: angular, icons

Here I have a piece of code where i have a arraylist containings some data and along with that data i have also used couple of icons among which one is favicon whose initial value is kept false..now i want to make this favicon clickable and on clicking it it should change its value to true and should turn into blue color.
I have used it in following way..

```
 <div class="col-6 "><span class="col-1 showicons favjob-false"></span>
```

i want this favjob to turn true on clicking, tried creating a function like

```
 <div class="col-6 "><span class="col-1 showicons favjob-false" (click)="fav()"></span>
```

but got stuck..so please do let me know how to do this.
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this..initially showfavjobIcon is false

```
<div 
    [class.favjob-false]="!showfavjobIcon"
    [class.favjob-true]="showfavjobIcon" (click)="showfavjobIcon=!showfavjobIcon">
```

Comment: this is working exactly how i wanted it to work..bt it is changing for all the elements of the array...need to change it individually..

Comment: can you once share the sample in stackblitz... so that i can understand the exact use case

Comment: Try using this..initially showfavjobIcon is false

`<div *ngFor="let fav of favIconsArray;let i of index">
    <div 
        [class.favjob-false]="!fav"
        [class.favjob-true]="fav" (click)="onFavClick(i)">
</div>`

In your ts file initially set the favIconsArray with a boolean value false untill its length is equal to arraylist

`onFavClick(i){
  this.favIconsArray[i]=!this.favIconsArray[i]
}`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulaar-aman-jobsite2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fjobdetails%2Fjobdetails.component.html @Anusha_Mamidala

Comment: Fixed it  `<span class="col-1 showicons favjob-false"  [class.favjob-false]="!s.favorite" [class.favjob-true]="s.favorite" (click)="s.favorite=!s.favorite"></span> 
             <span class=" col-1 showicons rupee"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

use `ngClass` and `ngStyle` directives

```
<div class="col-6 "><span class="col-1 showicons" [ngClass]="favJboClass"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color}"(click)="fav()"></span>

 favJboClass = 'favjob-false'
 color = 'default_color'
 fav(){

    this.favJboClass = 'favjob-true'
    this.color  = 'blue'
 }
```

Comment: i have couple of elements in the list it is changing all the favicon of all the element i want to change it individually..

Comment: create a object array including color and a class property